# Largest ratio between base and maximum RAM

Tags: history, memory

For example, the Apple II originally shipped with a base 4K of RAM but could be expanded to 48K, so the maximum was twelve times the base.

Of all the computers ever shipped, which one has had the largest such ratio? (I don't know if there was ever a machine that had no RAM at all in the base configuration, but if so, I'm not counting that.)

Comment: An original 16k IBM PC could be upgraded to 32MB using a extended (EMS) memory card. Probably never happened but there were extended memory cards that could take up 32MB of RAM and would work in 8-bit ISA  slot.

Comment: I wonder how many IBM PCs might actually have been shipped with 16kb

Comment: @tofro Probably a fair number. Even if they weren't good for much they were half the price ($1500 vs $3000) of a more usefully configured 64K machine with a floppy drive and display.

Comment: @Ross that’s a similar scale to that possible on modern high-end servers — RAM configurations start in the single-digit gigabyte range and go up to several terabytes... (Not sure about matching ×2048 though!)

Comment: @RossRidge I don't think that should count. IBM PCs could not address more than 1Mb + 64Kb - 16b directly, and there was no virtual memory mechanism yet; therefore that EMS was not RAM in the strict sense.

Comment: @tofro Remember that the original IBM PC had a cassette port, allowing that to be the storage device instead of floppy(ies). At that level, and with just 16 kbytes of RAM, it was inferior to a number of pre-existing home machines. I think the only "advanced" feature it had was the IBM name.

Comment: @LeoB I don't see how banked-switched RAM isn't RAM in a strict sense. It's no different than the bank-switched memory used by Z80-based Cambridge Z88 and Enterprise 64 computers mentioned in tofro's and Tommy's answers.

Comment: 386 systems commonly shipped with between 1–4 MB of RAM, but were capable of addressing up to 4 GB. That's a good 1024x ratio, or more. The issue with bank-switched memory to me is that the CPU can't actually address that much memory at once.

Comment: @RossRidge I think that bank switching should count when it allows as much flexibility as virtual memory, i. e. when one can map any page of the memory extension to any physical page in any combination, maybe with the exception of the interrupt and the I/O sections. LIM EMS 4.0 attempted to define this capability but it is unclear if it was ever fully implemented, let alone on an 8-bit ISA card.

Comment: @Cody but there never was a 386 system which could be expanded to 4GB of RAM...

Comment: @LeoB. I don't see how you can justify that restriction as anything other than arbitrary. Bank-switch RAM is RAM regardless of how "flexible" it is.

Comment: @RossRidge If a single window switched-bank view into the expanded memory is enough to consider it RAM, how would you define what should be the minimal window size to declare an external device a RAM extender? If you say "enough to execute instructions in the mapped region", then 1-2 bytes could be enough for a jump instruction, and every storage device with a memory-mapped I/O would qualify, making that definition useless. If you say "enough  to do useful work while executing instructions in the mapped region", then the definition becomes arbitrary.

Comment: @LeoB. I don't see the need to apply any arbitrary definitions here. You're the only one insisting on making them up.

Comment: @CodyGray The 386SX only had 24 address lines, so that's only 16Mb. The 386DX had 32 address lines, but no 386 computer of the period could support 4Gb of RAM due to the address decoding logic outside of the CPU.

Comment: I don't see how this question could really be answered because that same 4K base Apple II could be expanded to many megabytes using MMU's, bank switching, etc.  With CPLD/FPGA it could, in theory, go to GIGS with clever hacks like using the databus, etc.  So what's the upper end?  If it's unknown, then how can you calculate the ratio.

Comment: @cbmeeks Not without a soldering iron, it couldn't.

Comment: @JeremyP sure it could.  A clever FPGA designer could put a huge amount of RAM on a board and bank switch it in with all kinds of weird ways.  Granted, it may not be practical.  But it would work.  For example, the FPGA could monitor 2 bytes of RAM to generate a 16 bit address bus in addition to the 16 bit address bus of the 6502.  The programmer could set those 2 bytes to whatever and give the IIe 65,536 banks of 64K.  Would it break legacy software?  Oh I'm sure of it.  But that's not the point of the original question.

Comment: @cbmeeks I think the point of the original question was how far could you expand the system using officially supported means. It may be interesting to speculate how you might expand an Apple II with infinite amounts of memory, but it would be a bit of a stretch for the spirit of this question.

Comment: @cbmeeks I guess you'd have to limit such expansions to what was readily available at the time.

Comment: @cbmeeks Without any modern developments or custom designs, just using what was commercially available in the eatly 80s is at about 14 MiB when using seven 2 MiB RAM Cards. So with a 48KiB Baseram and language Card this restults in a 3600:1 ratio :))) **-** But you're right, the question needs either a clear definition what kind of expansion is acceptable or can't be answered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Altair 8800 shipped with 256 bytes of memory but the 8080 CPU could directly address 64K (with e.g. a Central Data 64K RAM Board), so that's 256×.

In the 1980s, Macrotech released a [2MB RAM board](http://www.s100computers.com/Hardware%20Folder/Macrotech/2MGRAM/2MG%20Board.htm) for the S-100 bus which supports 4 such boards, so that's 32,768×.

More recently, hobbyists have built [4MB RAM boards](http://www.s100computers.com/My%20System%20Pages/RAM%20Board/4MG%20RAM%20Board.htm), so that's 65,536× total.

Answer (score 21):

The Amiga 3000 shipped with 2 MB and is expandable with stock parts up to 1170 MB (4x 256 MB RAM card, 128 MB on CPU card, 18 MB on motherboard) - that's 585x. In theory, it could go up to a full 4 GB (2048x) but no hardware exists to do that.

For on-motherboard expansion, the Power Macintosh 9500 shipped with 32 MB and is expandable up to 1536 MB - that's 48x. My 9500 actually runs 1.5 GB.

For (somewhat) current server systems, 48:1 is rather easy to beat. Our (not quite retro yet) Dell R515 could be ordered with as little as 4 GB and is upgradable to 256 GB. More current systems can go up to several TB and probably start out as low as 8 or 16 GB.

When it comes to super computers, you could probably get six-digit ratios easily...

Comment: That is... wow! 11 unused address lines. Thanks for sharing this, and welcome to the site.

Comment: Thx! I've been reading for quite a while but hadn't had too much to post. ;-)

Comment: With super computers, I imagine you’d be limited by the base configuration, which tends to be quite large.

Comment: One example of a modern server setup is Dell’s R930 which starts at 8GB and can be configured with 12TB (although the specs say it only supports 3TB).

Comment: Re: the comment about modern servers; maybe the question could have been phrased on a logarithmic scale: approximately "how many spare address lines were there, proportionally", as an approximate measure of how much 'room for extra' was designed in? Then a ZX81 scales from 2^10 to 2^16 bytes of RAM, so that's a logarithmic multiplier of 1.6. The Amiga goes from 2^21 to around 2^30.2, so that's a multiplier of around 1.43. The Dell goes from 2^32 up to 2^38 so that's around 1.19. From 8gb to 12tb would be ~1.32. Etc.

Answer (score 8):

The Sinclair ZX-81 came with a single K of memory and could be expanded to 64kBytes (using third-party memory expansions, Memotech, for example).

I think none of the later (home) computers ever managed to exceed that 64-fold expansion option.

*Theoretical* expandability is maybe beaten by the Cambridge Z88 that came with 32kBytes of main memory and theoretically could have been expanded to 4MBytes (128-fold). Some of this address range would, however, have been used for mass storage on plug-in cards, so it was not really feasible to use all of this range for main memory.

Comment: In terms of actual RAM you could touch though, the ZX81 surely topped out at 56kb? Though you could hit 60kb on a ZX80. In both cases I'm thinking of the ROM size.

Comment: @Tommy The original as it came from the shop was advertised as 64k, but only had 56k usable. You could, however, modify this and copy ROM to RAM with some modifications.

Comment: Even the basic 1K ZX81 with the factory 16K expansion pack is 16:1 which beats the 12:1 of the Apple II in the question.

Comment: @JeremyP Well, the Apple II also got a *factory 16k pack*, aka language card, so the ratio here is also 16:1 :)) I think the question needs a better definition what does count, 'cause otherwise one could put seven 2 MiB RAM Cards in, totaling in a 3600:1 ratio :))

Answer (score 7):

An additional 64x option: the [Enterprise 64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enterprise_(computer)) came with the 64kb the name implies, and the base hardware implements a paging scheme of up to 256 separate 16kb segments — a 64 multiplier since that's 256*16/64, and 4mb total.

Technical documentation seems to be sparse, but see e.g. [this page](http://ep.lgb.hu/doc/Dave.html) and R16 to R21. The top two bits of the Z80's inherent 16-bit address bus are replaced with 8 by table lookup. So it's a 22-bit address bus, right there in the base machine.

You'll likely find other machines for which similar paging schemes provide similar RAM limits, but I think this is a rare example of the scheme being fully implemented in the base hardware.

---

I've already been outgunned, but another high multiple is the Mac SE/30, which shipped with 1mb in its lowest configuration but can be upgraded to 128mb. Apple's official documentation gives a limit of 32mb, but that's just because of the size of SIMMs available at launch. No hardware modifications are required to support 128mb of RAM.

Comment: I was thinking about mentioning the Enterprise (as I have one in my collection and like it very much) - There was, however, afaik no commercial offering of memory expansion that would actually have used the possible limit. I happen to have some EP128 advertisements of Enterprise Germany where the maximum available was an expansion to 576kBytes.

Comment: @tofro yeah, I wasn't sure where to draw the line on that. I figured that the base hardware having 22 address lines, that you could point at, its designers having intending that the user be able to fit that much memory, was sufficient. So I guess I went with: address lines usable without modification or additional hardware versus installed memory. Which is not to discount contemporaneous commercial modifications, just another option.

Comment: I had my Enterprise upgraded to 2MB for a short time - I didn't have many programs that could actually make use of that much memory, and the initial memory test taking so long annoyed me so much that I have now reduced it to 256k ;)

Answer (score 3):

This answer doesn't win the contest at all, but I include it for interest's sake and the hope to inspire future readers to play with the hardware.

The Commodore VIC-20 shipped with 5 kB of RAM and officially expanded to 32 kB, but very easily, and even using hardware available in the first year or so of its existence, it could be expanded to 40 kB (3 kB expander or SuperExpander [the latter of which had BASIC language enhancements], 16 kB expander, and 2 x 8 kB expanders [with their DIP switches configured appropriately so that the RAM doesn't overlap).  That's an 8x multiplier over the stock RAM.  Unlike some of the other competitors, *all* VIC-20s shipped with 5 kB so this would be a very normal multiplier.

Today, it's even easier to expand a VIC-20 as there are many, many RAM expanders available.  32 kB expanders are very easy to find, and adding a 3 kB expander and a cartridge slot expander will attain the same result.  (There may even be single-cartridge ways of adding the entire 35 kB additional RAM required, but if there are, I'm not aware of them.)

Answer (score 1):

If you allow addition of bank-switched RAM, the ratio can get very silly. For example, the 16KB Sinclair ZX Spectrum could have been expanded using an upgrade whose schematics were published in the Your Spectrum magazine (and which was also available as an assembled module, IIRC) up to 4MB, is by a factor of 256.  I believe the same system could have been used with little or modification on a ZX81 (originally sold with just 1KB RAM) for a factor of 4096 expansion.

Custom built hardware could of course have taken it even further. But I'm not sure there would have been much point. Fully populating that 4MB expansion in 1986 would have cost somewhere between £500 and £1000, and the RAM chips (512 of them) would have dissipated a somewhat cozy 10W at idle and closer to 100W during a refresh cycle. I don't know whether anyone actually did it at the time.